# Non-clickable area on transforming anchor

Tags: html, css, transform

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/olexander/7hB8C/

I have an anchor, which is styled as a button (the styles are simplified to show the issue).

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button demo">Button</a>
```

CSS:

```
.button {
    border: none;
    outline: none;    
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

.button:active {
    transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
    -o-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
}

.demo {
    padding: 40px;
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 5em;
    color: black;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

The issue is that there is a non-clickable area inside the link-button.
I can explain it that there is a text node inside the anchor, and when mousedown goes to the text node, after transform, mouseup comes outside the text node. That's why mouseclick is not processed.

If we select the text node inside the anchor, it can be visualized like this (before and after mousedown):
[image: click on the border of text node doesn't fire click event]

I would like to notice, that the issue is reproduced at least in Chrome, Opera and Safari, and even if I put a link to href tag instead of handling click event. It is also reproduced with `<button>`, and not the issue for `<input type="button">`, because the first one uses content, and the second value.

Does anyone have ideas about better ways to avoid or workaround this behavior? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

I found a solution using a streched "stub" `<span>` to override the clickable area:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button"><span class="stub"></span>Button</a>
```

and the stub styles:

```
.button > span.stub {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

This version is published here: http://jsfiddle.net/olexander/7hB8C/20/

The stub can be added dynamically by javascript, but the idea remains the same.
Since the inline span element can be nested inside anchors and buttons, it doesn't break the W3C HTML5/XHTML5 rules.

And Aequanox made the solution perfect! Look at the answer below.

The whole story is published here: [Animated anchor and button with css3](http://ivanitskyi.blogspot.com/2013/03/animated-anchor-and-button-with-css3.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid inserting the  tag, thus mantaining the markup cleaner, by inserting this in the css:

```
.button:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
 }
```

The text will not be selectable though

Comment: That's perfect! Great!
And works in all major modern browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Abefore

Answer (score 1):

It seems the `:active` transition is replacing the click event. I'd consider this a browser bug.

Here I've changed `:active` to a class name `.active` and apply is in your event handler:

```
$('#linkbutton').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');    
    $(this).delay(200).queue(function() { $(this).removeClass('active');})
    $('#logContainer').append('<span>clicked </span>');    
});
```

For some reason this didn't work until I changed .button from:

```
display: inline-block;
```

to:

```
float: left;
```

Go figure... It works now though.

Comment: Thanks for efforts!
But since it behaves the same in different browsers, I'd consider this a browsers feature:)

Comment: Well, this approach basically works, but it should be much improved of course, and I'm afraid this improving may end up with developing a jquery plugin...
Generally I wouldn't like to have any click event handlers, as the _button_ class is supposed to be applied to normal links to make them behave as buttons.
Btw, it works with _display: inline-block_, but _.dequeue()_ should be specified after _removeClass()_.
Your version is saved to http://jsfiddle.net/olexander/7hB8C/12/

Comment: @Diodeus I wouldn't say the click event is replaced; I would say that you are just outside of the clickable area (that has become smaller). So, imho, that wouldn't be a bug.