# clickable area of a button that scales down on click

Tags: javascript, css

I have an element which is acting as a button with a little Javascript and CSS. I'll strip it down to the most bare example, so you can see the problem. The issue originates from the fact that the element is scaled down when it's clicked. Javascript interprets the *clickable* area of the button as its scaled down size, not the original size. This occurs in all modern desktop browsers.

Here are the important parts. HTML:

```
<div id="refresh">more</div>
```

CSS:

```
#refresh {
    background-color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 150ms ease-out;
}

#refresh:active {
    transform: scale(0.8);
}
```

JS:

```
var refreshBtn = document.getElementById("refresh");

function newImg() {
    // updates an image elsewhere
}

// an event listener based on 
// http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/10/_and_the_winner_1.html
addEvent(refreshBtn, 'click', newImg);
```

So my image gets updated when I click on the area occupied by the *scaled down* button, defined by `transform: scale(0.8)`. If I click outside of that area, in the outer 20% of my button, my JS does not update the image. The proper click transitions occur and the cursor displays correctly as a `pointer`, but the JS does not count this area as part of the `onclick` event.

This was covered here, but I find the solution unappealing:
[Non-clickable area on transforming anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187419/non-clickable-area-on-transforming-anchor)

The same solution is offered here:
[increasing clickable area of a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246893/increasing-clickable-area-of-a-button)

Here's the CSS I used as outlined in those answers:

```
#refresh:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: -12%;
    right: -12%;
    left: -12%;
    bottom: -12%;
}
```

These ensure that Javascript now recognizes a bigger clickable area instead of the scaled-down area, but in turn the pointer and the CSS hover effects now react to hovering and clicking well *outside* the original button element. I consider it an ugly solution. Surely someone else has run into this problem before. Are there any nicer solutions?

Update: Here is a jsfiddle of the situation I've explained: http://jsfiddle.net/cx9ur44e/4/

Comment: Can you include a jsfiddle? http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Here we go. Tried to make it mimic my actual document but kept it fairly simple. Try clicking on the outer half of the button, and the alert window will not execute: http://jsfiddle.net/cx9ur44e/4/

Answer (score 1):

To solve the issue of the size, you would need to add the click even to a wrapper of the button that will keep the size even if the button is active.

```
<div id="wrapper>
    <div id="refresh">more</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems that deadzone of the area being scaled still manages to interfere with the event listener placed on the wrapper, and no function is called when I click within that outer area. I even tried placing the wrapper on a higher `z-index` but it doesn't seem to have an effect. It's as if the area to be scaled is not being considered a part of the box model.

Comment: Update - the problem seems to be occurring in Firefox and Opera. The behaviour of the wrapper seems to be correct in Chrome and IE.